# Not able to mount ext4 file-system in Debian Lenny

Tags: debian, filesystems, ext4

I am trying to mount `ext4` EBS volume in to my EC2 instance in `Debian` OS, whenever I try to mount I get the following error:

> mount: unknown filesystem type 'ext4'

I googled around and found a link to the solution: http://techtitbits.com/2010/05/mounting-ext4-partitions-on-debian/

No luck, now I get this problem:

> mount: unknown filesystem type 'ext4dev'

Not sure what is the exact problem in mounting `ext4` file-system. Please help.

Thanks for your time.

**NOTE**

My kernel version is: 2.6.21.7-2.ec2.v1.2.fc8xen

Debian OS is Lenny 5.0

```
**ANSWER**

PLEASE DO NOT MOUNT Ext4 filesystem on kernel version < 2.6.28, it will not work, 
since Ext4 was introduced only in >= 2.6.28 kernel version.
```

Please see: http://wiki.debian.org/Ext4

Comment: `lsmod | grep ext4` or `grep -i ext4 /path/to/the/kernel/.config`?

Comment: `lsmod` shows nothing, whereas with kernel/.config - I am not sure I know the path to kernel folder, can you help me with that?

Comment: Take a look at `/usr/src/linux...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PLEASE DO NOT MOUNT Ext4 filesystem on `kernel version < 2.6.28`, it will not work, 
since Ext4 was introduced only in >= 2.6.28 kernel version.

Please see: http://wiki.debian.org/Ext4

Answer (score 2):

Don't do it.  The experimental ext4 module that was included in Lenny isn't safe or sane to use on a disk that you actually want to store data on.

Still, the mount operation should work alright once the test_fs flag is set.  What's the exact output from these commands, filled in with the relevant info for your system?

```
tune2fs -E test_fs /dev/sdXX
mount -t ext4dev -o ro /dev/sdXX /mnt/mountpoint
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Shane-madden, it looks like Ext4 is introduced in `Linux Kernel version > 2.6.28` ([from this link](http://wiki.debian.org/Ext4)), where as my version is `2.6.21` :-( - that said I will have to upgrade my kernel version and give it a try.